# Javascript validation for multiple textboxes

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I am having some trouble figuring out how to validate my textboxes using js.  I have 10 textboxes, the user can fill out any number 1-10, but cant fill out 0.  Here is the js that I have written, but it only returns true if all 10 textboxes are filled, rather than just checking if one is filled.

```
    function submitIt() {
    if (document.isForm.Student_ID.value == null) {
        alert ("You must enter a Colleague ID.");
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And here is the form.....

```
<form name="isForm" onSubmit="return submitIt()">
    <input name="Student_ID" type="text" id="idField1" />
    <input name="Student_ID" type="text" id="idField2" />
    <input name="Student_ID" type="text" id="idField3" />
    <input name="Student_ID" type="text" id="idField4" />
    <input name="Student_ID" type="text" id="idField5" />
    <input name="Student_ID" type="text" id="idField6" />
    <input name="Student_ID" type="text" id="idField7" />
    <input name="Student_ID" type="text" id="idField8" />
    <input name="Student_ID" type="text" id="idField9" />
    <input name="Student_ID" type="text" id="idField10" />
    <input name="SUBMIT" type="submit" />
</form>
```

I realize that I could change all of the names, and check each one, but I am trying to avoid that much clutter in my code, and am curious the best way to do this.  Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: you don't need to change all the names... you can simply loop through all the inputs inside your form tag and break out as soon as an input has a value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get a collection of all these textboxes with `document.getElementsByName`.  Then loop through them, and make sure at least one is filled in:

```
var allTbs = document.getElementsByName("Student_ID");
var valid = false;
for (var i = 0, max = allTbs.length; i < max; i++) {
    if (allTbs[i].value) { 
       valid = true;
       break;
    }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/3Fvyr/2/)

Comment: +1, I hadn't come across `getElementsByName()` before! So I was taking a slower way to do the same thing... =)

Comment: @David - yeah, there's a lot of neat stuff in the dom that using jQuery can make you unaware of (I only knew it existed because I spend so much time here on SO :) )

Comment: I must confess that I 'learned' jQuery first (the similarity with CSS-selection was its attraction), but I am now moving towards preferring 'plain' JavaScript, now. With the exception of handling cross-browser problems. Plus, to be fair, given other JavaScript means of accessing Node collections, I really should've *guessed* that `getElementsByName()` existed... =)

Comment: Good answer. You could also use: `var allTbs=document.isForm.Student_ID;`

Comment: That's a good point, @graphicdivine - would probably be even faster

Comment: Although, I think you'd want `document.forms["formID"].Student_ID.length`

Answer (score 0):

Function is iterating by all of the student text boxes and return true if some element is filled out. Protected against that if input contain only spaces :)

```
   function submitIt() {
      for( var i = 0, t = document.getElementsByName( "Student_ID" ), l = t.length; i < l; i++ )     
         if( t[i].value && !/^\s+$/.test( t[i].value ) )
            return true;

      return false 
   }
```

Demo on: http://jsfiddle.net/hhD2x/

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery.
add common class name for all your textboxes i.e.

```
<input name="Student_ID" type="text" id="idField1" class="student" />
```

now in js function

```
function submit()
{
        $('.student').each(function() {
           if($(this).val() == '' || $(this).val() == null)
           {
                // your error message
                return false;
           }

       }
}
```

this function check all the elements with student class.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[type="text"], select,
   :input[type="date"],
   :input[type="email"],
   :input[type="radio"]').each(function () {

  if ($.trim($(this).val()) == '' ) {
    // your error message here
    isValid = false;
  }

});
```

Comment: Formatting, it needs it.