# How to check any text box is not empty on jsp page?

Tags: jsp, textbox, submit

I have number of text boxes on jsp page. I want to check that every text boxes are not empty when I submit. When I submit and if any text box is empty than it should not allow to submit to servlet page. How to check that for multiple text boxes?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkvalue() { 
    var mystring = document.getElementById('uname').value;
    var mystring1 = document.getElementById('pass').value; 
    if(!mystring.match(/\S/) && !mystring1.match(/\S/))
        {
            alert ('Empty value is not allowed');
            return false;
        }
    else 
        {
            alert("correct input");
            return true;
        }
    }
```

I have tried javascript as above. I just want to know how to reduce code for multiple text boxes?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8747328/javascript-validation-for-multiple-textboxes

Comment: http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/12/jquery-to-check-all-textboxes-empty.html

Comment: [Duplicate, find answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8747328/javascript-validation-for-multiple-textboxes) Here, you will find full explanation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8747328/javascript-validation-for-multiple-textboxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jquery validations and server side validations are there only but if you still want to implement custom validation, then you should make changes like following.

```
function checkvalue() { 
var returnValue = true;
$(".TxtBox").each(function(el,ue){ 
    if(!$(ue).match(/\S/)
    {
         alert("Empty value is not allowed");
         returnValue = false;
    }
    return returnValue;
})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkvalue() { 
    var mystring = document.getElementById('uname').value;
    var mystring1 = document.getElementById('pass').value; 
    if(!mystring.match(/\S/) && !mystring1.match(/\S/))
        {
            alert ('Empty value is not allowed');
            return false;
        }
    else 
        {
            alert("correct input");
            return true;
        }
    }
```

I have tried javascript as above. i just want to know how to reduce code for multiple text boxes?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the onclick event on submit button, and removing action attribute in form tag if any. Inside onclick event handler function, you check whether all the checkboxes are checked or not using.. document.getElementById("checkBoxId").checked - which returns true/false; After this validation you can do submit on the form using document.form['formId'].submit();

Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: thank you for your help. can you please tell me that do i have to check for each text box separate in javascript?? it would be great help...