# Regular expression for LastName, FirstName with space

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using the below JS to enter name in LastName, FirstName format like this `Clark, Michael` and now I also probably need to allow names like this `Tim Duncan, Vince Carter` where these kinda names have space in between.

```
function validateName(txtbox) {
        var name = /^\w{1,20}\, \w{1,20}$/
        var check = document.getElementById(txtbox);
        if (check != null) {
            if (check.value != "") {
                if (!name.test(check.value)) {
                    alert('Please enter name in Last Name, First Name format');
                    document.getElementById(txtbox).focus();
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else if (name.test(check.value)) {
                return true;
            }
            else if (check.value == "") {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there any way to achieve this by a change within the same Regex. Really appreciate suggestions and help.

Comment: 20 characters max? Data processed by a Sinclair ZX81? ;-)

Comment: What about `O'connors` or `Jean-François`?

Comment: @M42 - I'm looking for a solution for that case and pls help if you could.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
^[\w ]{1,20}\, [\w ]{1,20}$
```

This should work for you.

Comment: This worked for what I 've asked. I think I should 've been more clear. I also have names like this `George Timothy, Clooney` and `Bradley, William Pitt` that I should be able to enter.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this will meet your expectations.

`/^\s*(\w{1,20} *[^,]*)+,\s+(\w{1,20}\s*)+$/`

However above regex will accept also multiple white spaces before and after name. If you want to force only one space character format you should use these regex:

`/^(\w{1,20} ?[^,]*)+, (\w{1,20}( [^$]|$))+$/`

Comment: Everything is fine, but I need to add space after comma like this `George Timothy, Clooney` and `Bradley, William Pitt`. Also character limit will be increased.

Comment: I've edited my post. I guess you don't need character limits for all input value but only for names, right?

Answer (score 2):

You can use **html5** pattern..

```html
<input type="text" title="Following format: FirstName LastName" pattern="^\s*([\w]{1,20}( |,)?)+\s*,\s+([\w]{1,20} *)+$" />
```